# When I use an access token of Microsoft Graph, Access failed and response 400 error

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I trying to use Microsoft Graph on Java. I succeed to get an access token.

But, when I use this token via HttpURLConnection, my access has been denied and catched 400 error from microsoft server.

```
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    String url_str = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
    String bearer_token = "EwA4A8l6BA...";

    URL url = new URL(url_str);
    con = ( HttpURLConnection )url.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer " + bearer_token);
    con.setRequestProperty("Host","graph.microsoft.com");
    con.connect();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream() )); // Error has been occured here.
    String str = null;
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        str += line;
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

Here is error message.

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

But, this access token acquired in Java,
It works normally when used with another program.

Here is my PowerShell source code.(I got the results as expected.)

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Uri ( "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me" ) `
  -Method Get `
  -Headers @{
      Authorization = "Bearer EwA4A8l6BA...";
  } `
  -ErrorAction Stop;
```

What is the cause of this? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry. I solved my problem by myself.
This problem has been occured that my server does not accept the json response.

So, I added an "Accept: application/json" in request header.

Therefore, this is correct source code.

```
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    String url_str = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
    String bearer_token = "EwA4A8l6BA...";

    URL url = new URL(url_str);
    con = ( HttpURLConnection )url.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer " + bearer_token);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json"); // I added this line.
    con.connect();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream() ));
    String str = null;
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        str += line;
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

I hope this post helps someone.